# Method call throws "Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task", but same code works in main project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method `SendEmail` that is called from an interface and throws: `System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Microsoft.Graph.IUserSendMailRequest.PostAsync()'.'` The application does not even hit the breakpoint at the start of the method.

The method described in the exception is part of `SendEmail` code, which is found in a Class Library project that is referenced by an ASP.NET Core application (both .NET 6.0). If I copy paste the `SendEmail` code into a test Controller, it works fine.

Why doesn't the code work when calling `SendEmail` from the interface? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be a mismatch between the library (Microsoft.Graph) containing `Microsoft.Graph.IUserSendMailRequest.PostAsync()` method. The Class Library project containing `SendEmail` was using an older version (3.35.0). Normally, this is not a problem since the compiler upgrades to the newer version (4.34.0) found in the ASP.NET Core project. However, in this case things didn't work at runtime.

This indicates that the new version is not backwards compatible with the old one, although the same code compiles with both of them. Basically, `SendEmail` code was compiled with the old library version and was linked with the new one at runtime.

The solution was to use the same version of Microsoft.Graph in both projects.